# Map with same object as key value

Tags: java, hashmap

Is it technically bad design to have a Map where Foo1 and Foo2 could technically be equal but you still want them to have different qualities about them such that:

```
  Foo foo2 = new Foo("id1", 4);
    Foo foo1 = map.get(foo2);
    if(foo1 != null){
        map.replace(foo1, foo1.combine(foo2));
    }
```

Doesn't this technically violate "Equals"? I noticed in `Multiset` there is no `get` function which makes sense because if the set contains the object, you already have it, so no need to retrieve it.

But at the same time, it seems like over kill to have a map that contains the key and value as same object which is why I was looking into Multiset

Edit: combine returns the same object that still "equals" but combines attributes.

I.E.

```
public class Foo {
String id;
int length;

public combine(Foo foo){
   this.length += foo.length;
   return this;
}

@Override equals(Object o){
...
return this.id == that.id;
}
```

Comment: what is `combination()`

Comment: just combines the two to the same object, i.e. if foo1 and foo2 had length, then it would add the lengths together. but it still returns object that contains same "equals" attributes

Comment: equals should identify an object uniquely. If you want the above behaviour, then foo1 and foo2 should return the same value for hashCode(). You should then combine them based on that I think. And then call containsKey(foo1) and do your merge operation on that bases.

Comment: so you're saying it's okay with the above implementation, just that the hashcode would be a hash of the id?

Comment: I still think it's a bit weird, but this would be the contract for hashcode() and equals(). hashCode() for 2 objects can be the same without them being equal(). Equal() should only return true when they are in fact identical. By what you are saying, they are not identical, but you want to identify objects that are  "kind of equal enough". For that I would use the hashCode() indicating that they belong to the same merge object, but are not equal, hence having to be merged. Does that make sense?

Comment: makes sense, but what if hash code collides with another hash code that isn't considered "equals enough"? where would I create this restriction

Comment: In that case, I would add a new interface Mergeable that implements a method saying canMerge(OtherObject) which returns true only if those 2 objects can be merged. Thinking about that, this is probably the better solution anyway. THe issue with your approach is, that all throughout the java world, classes rely on the correctness of equals and hashcode, and you abusing it will have all sorts of wonky side effects down the road.

Comment: your canMerge I think will work great, can you please post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equals and hashcode have a contract that other classes rely on to be correctly implemented. I would not abuse those methods to solve this.

Better solution is to have a custom interface

```
public interface MergeAble<T> {

   public boolean canMerge(T other);

}
```

Your object can then implement this and you can have custom logic for merging for those objects implemented in your own interface.